# Dividing line by module in multiprocessing

Tags: python, process, queue, multiprocessing

I want to put a huge file into small files. There are approximately 2 million IDs in file and I want sort them by module. When you run program it should ask the number of files that you want to divide the main file.(x= int(input)). And I want to seperate file by module function. I mean if ID%x == 1 it should ad this ID to q1 and to f1. But it adds only first line that true for requirements.

```
import multiprocessing
    def createlist(x,i,queue_name):
        with open("events.txt") as f:
            next(f)
            for line in f:
                if int(line) % x == i:
                    queue_name.put(line)
    def createfile(x,i,queue_name):
        for i in range(x):
            file_name = "file{}.txt".format(i+1)
            with open(file_name, "w") as text:
                text.write(queue_name.get())
    if __name__=='__main__':
        x= int(input("number of parts "))
        i = 0
        for i in range(x):
            queue_name = "q{}".format(i+1)
            queue_name = multiprocessing.Queue()
            p0=multiprocessing.Process(target = createlist, args = (x,i,queue_name,))
            process_name = "p{}".format(i+1)
            process_name = multiprocessing.Process(target = createfile, args = (x,i,queue_name,))
            p0.start()
            process_name.start()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `createfile` has two functional issues.

1. it only reads from the queue once, then terminates
2. it iterates the range of the desired number of subsets a second time, hence even after fixing the issue with the single queue-read you get one written file and `parts - 1` empty files.

To fix your approach make `createfile` look like this:

```
def createfile(i, queue_name): # Note: x has been removed from the args
    file_name = "file{}.txt".format(i + 1)
    with open(file_name, "w") as text:
        while True:
            if queue.empty():
                break
            text.write(queue.get())
```

Since `x` has been removed from `createfile`'s arguments, you'd also remove it from the process instantiation:

```
process_name = multiprocessing.Process(target = createfile, args = (i,queue_name,))
```

---

However ... do not do it like this. The more subsets you want, the more processes and queues you create (two processes and one queue per subset). That is **a lot** of overhead you create.

Also, while having one responsible process per output file for writing might still make *some* sense, having multiple processes reading the same (huge) file completely does not.

I did some timing and testing with an input file containing 1000 lines, each consisting of one random integer between 0 and 9999. I created three algorithms and ran each in ten iterations while tracking execution time. I did this for a desired number of subsets of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 10. For the graph below I took the mean value of each series.

[image: execution time]

**orwqpp (green):** Is one-reader-writer-queue-per-part. *Your* approach. It saw an average increase in execution time of 0.48 seconds per additional subset.

**orpp (blue):** Is one-reader-per-part. This one had a common writer process that took care of writing to all files. It saw an average increase in execution time of 0.25 seconds per additional subset.

**ofa (yellow):** Is one-for-all. One single function, not run in a separate process, reading and writing in one go. It saw an average increase in execution time of 0.0014 seconds per additional subset.

Keep in mind that these figures were created with an input file 1/2000 the size of yours. The processes in what resembles your approach completed so quickly, they barely got in each other's way. Once the input is large enough to make the processes run for a longer amount of time, contention for CPU resources will increase and so will the penalty of having more processes as more subsets are requested.

Here's the one-for-all approach:

```
def one_for_all(parts):
    handles = dict({el: open("file{}.txt".format(el), "w") for el in range(parts)})
    with open("events.txt") as f:
        next(f)
        for line in f:
            fnum = int(line) % parts
            handles.get(fnum).write(line)
    [h.close() for h in handles.values()]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = int(input("number of parts "))
    one_for_all(x)
```

This currently names the files based on the result of the modulo operation, so numbers where `int(line) % parts` is 0 will be in `file0.txt` and so on.
if you don't want that, simply add 1 when formatting the file name:

```
handles = dict({el: open("file{}.txt".format(el+1), "w") for el in range(parts)})
```